# How to sort a key value pair of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I have this array getting fetched from `firebase` and I have been trying to map that array and the array is in key value pair

```
{
  A: {name: "test1", views: "20"},
  B: {name: "test2", views: "30"},
  C: {name: "test3", views: "23"}
}
```

I want to either map them or if I can reverse this array like

```
{ C: {}, B: {}, A: {}}
```

I'm doing all this in react native so please suggest some solution to it.

Comment: what you have above is not an array, it is an object with several objects

Comment: [] = Array, {} = Object

Comment: what do you want to do, it doesn't make sense to change positions in an object (dictionary)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just sort it alphabetically.

```
const unsorted = {
    A: {name: "test1", views: "20"},
    B: {name: "test2", views: "30"},
    C: {name: "test3", views: "23"}
}

const sorted = {};
Object.keys(unsorted).sort().forEach(key =>  {
  sorted[key] = unsorted[key];
});
```

or reverse alphabetically sorted one.

```
Object.keys(unsorted).sort().reverse().forEach(key =>  {
  sorted[key] = unsorted[key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So i was searching the web and found this
As above you guys suggested it is not an array it is an Object and can be sorted this way

```
let list = Object.entries(snapshot.val())
    .sort(function (x, y) {
      return x[1].spectators - y[1].spectators;
    })
    .reverse();
```

this is for descending order for ascending remove reverse()

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Reversing the sequence in which keys are extracted from an object is a bit annoying because you have to take them all out and then place them back all in in the order you want:

```
function reverse(o) {
    let entries = Object.entries(o).reverse();
    entries.forEach(e => delete o[e[0]]);
    entries.forEach(e => o[e[0]] = e[1]);
}
```

This code works by mutating the object, thus maintaining eventually references from other objects to this one valid; mutating the object is also important to maintain the correct prototype of the object if it wasn't the default. If you want to clone it instead you should be careful about copying the same prototype.